# Construction of an isomorphism for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Good evening!

I'm a bit confused by questions requiring me to "construct an isomorphism".

a) Construct an isomorphism between $\Bbb{M}_{3\times 4}(\Bbb{R})$ and $\Bbb{M}_{2\times 6}(\Bbb{R})$.

b) Consider the subspace $W = \{A \in \Bbb{M}_{n×n}(\Bbb{R}) | A = A^T \}$ of $\Bbb{M}_{n×n}(\Bbb{R})$. For what value of $m$ is $W$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$? Construct an isomorphism between $W$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$.

I know a linear transformation is an isomorphism if it is bijective.

a) $3\times 4$ matrix, the maximum dimension will be $3$, since this is the number of linearly independent rows. The second matrix will have dimension $2$. Thus there is no isomorphism between them?

b) $W$ should be a square matrix? Like $2 \times 2, 3\times 3$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $3\times4=2\times6$ is the dimension of $M_{3\times4}(\mathbb R)$ and $M_{6\times2}(\mathbb R)$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb R$

Comment: Oh, so this notation implies the number of vectors to construct vector space. My bad

Comment: The *row space* of an $i\times j$ matrix is not the same thing as the *space of $i\times j$ matrices*. The former depends on a chosen matrix, while the latter depends only on $i$, $j$, and the underlying field.